# Will non-awaited async functions definitely attempt finish in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

It's my understanding that controllers get destroyed after an http request is made. Is there any assurances that the .NET Core runtime will wait until all threads initiated in an async action have terminated/ended before destroying the controller instance?

I have code below with an async controller action that calls an async function. I don't need to know if the async function actually succeeds or not (e.g. sending the email), I just want to make sure that it attempts to. My fear is that the .NET Core runtime will possibly kill the thread in the middle of execution.

Spoiler alert I ran the code below in my development environment and it does send the email every time (I put a real email). But I don't know if the behavior would change in a production environment.

Any thoughts/guidance?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task SendEmail()
{
    // If I would prefix this with 'await' the controller
    // action doesn't terminate until the async function returns
    this.InternalSendEmail();
}

private async Task InternalSendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        await this.Email.Send("to@example.com", "Interesting subject", "Captivating content");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log(exc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe he wants the API call to return immediately and not wait for the email to be sent.

Comment: @mason he even shows the exception being logged.

Comment: @mason Won't it go to the catch block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What happens to the controller instance - nothing you can't manage**

First, when we talk about destroying the controller instance let's be more precise. The instance won't get GCd as long as there's still a control flow that has access to `this`. It can't. So your controller instance will be fine in that regard at least until your private method finishes.

What will happen is your controller method will return and control flow will go to the next stage in the middleware chain, meaning your API consumer will likely get the http response before the email is sent. **You will lose your `HttpContext` and all that goes with it when this happens**. Thus if there's anything in your `Log` method or anything else in `InternalSendEmail` that relies on the `HttpContext` you need to make sure that information is extracted and provided to the background method before the controller method returns.

**What happens to the thread - almost certainly nothing**

As far as the thread goes, most likely the email will be sent on a different thread in the thread pool from that of the original controller method, but either way, no the .NET runtime isn't going to care about your controller method returning before every task it fired off has completed, let alone kill the thread. That's well above its paygrade. Moreover it's very rare for threads to be killed in any instance these days because it's not just your control flow that's affected but completely unrelated async contexts could be dependent on that thread too.

**IIS Application Pool recycling and other things that COULD potentially kill your background task**

The only reasonably likely thing that would cause your background task not to complete would be if the *process* terminated. This happens for example during an IIS Application Pool reset (or equivalent if you're using dotnet hosting), obviously a server restart, etc. It can also happen if there's a catastrophic event like running out of memory, or nasty things like memory faults unique to unsafe or native code. But these things would kill all pending HTTP requests too.

I have seen anecdotal assertions that if there are no pending HTTP requests it makes it more likely that IIS will recycle the application pool on its own even if you have other active code running. After many years of maintaining an application that uses a very similar pattern for many non-critical long-running tasks, I have not seen this happen in practice (and we log every application start to a local TXT file so we would know if this were happening). So I am personally skeptical of this, though I welcome someone providing an authoritative source proving me wrong.

That said, we do set the application pool to reset every day at 4 AM, so to the extent that IIS would be inclined to involuntarily reset our app pools (as it *does* need to happen every now and then) I suspect this helps mitigate that, and would recommend it regardless. We also allow only one CPU process per application, rather than allowing IIS to fire off processes whenever it feels like it; I suspect this also makes it less likely IIS would kill the process involuntarily.

**In sum - this is perfectly fine for non-critical tasks**

I would not use this for critical tasks where unambiguous acknowledgement of success or failure is needed, such as in life critical applications. But for 99+% of real world applications what you're doing is perfectly fine as long as you account for the things discussed above and have some reasonable level of fault tolerance and failsafes in place, which the fact that you're logging the exception shows you clearly do.

PS - If you're interested in having robust progress reporting and you aren't familiar with it, I would look into SignalR, which would allow you to notify the client of a successful email send (or anything else) even after the API call returns, and is shockingly easy to use. Plus an open websocket connection would almost certainly prevent IIS from mistaking a returned API method for an opportunity to kill the process.

Comment: I should add for completeness that in IIS I also set the site to `AlwaysRunning`. So it's entirely possible that I don't observe forced resets as often as others suggest they might occur, because of my IIS settings.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any assurances that the .NET Core runtime will wait until all threads initiated in an async action have terminated/ended before destroying the controller instance?

No, this is absolutely not guaranteed.

> I don't need to know if the async function actually succeeds or not (e.g. sending the email), I just want to make sure that it attempts to. My fear is that the .NET Core runtime will possibly kill the thread in the middle of execution.

You cannot be sure that it will attempt to do so. The thread (and entire process) may be terminated at any time after the HTTP response is sent. In general, request-extrinsic code is not guaranteed to complete.

Some people are fine with losing some work (e.g., in this case, missing some emails). I'm not, so my systems are all built on a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog.

It's important to note that work can be lost during any shutdown, and shutdowns are *normal:*

- Any rolling upgrade triggers shutdowns (i.e., application updates).
- IIS/ASP.NET recycles every 19 hours by default.
- Runtime and OS patches require shutdowns.
- Cloud hosting causes shutdowns (both at the VM level and higher levels).

Bottom line: shutdowns are normal, and shutdowns cause any currently-running request-extrinsic work to be lost. If you're fine with occasionally losing work, then OK; but if you require an *assurance* that the work is done, then you'll need a basic distributed architecture (a durable queue with a background processor).

Comment: "The thread ... may be terminated at any time after the HTTP response is sent". Please cite a source for this. And specifically cite support for the idea that something OTHER THAN a process restart (app pool reset, etc., which I address in my answer) could cause an un-awaited task outside a request context not to complete. None of the things you cite are dependent on the request being alive or not.

Comment: The OP also specifically says he doesn't care about knowing if the request was successful. I've seen you post on this topic before, and read your blog, and what I see in both is a "perfect being the enemy of the good" philosophy. Ultimately the only additional risk of "request-extrinsic" code failing vs. "request-intrinsic" code is that the API caller won't necessarily know immediately. However there are myriad ways to address this, a queue being just one (and the most expensive one at that).

Comment: @PeterMoore: The thread will be terminated when the process shuts down. As explained on my blog, the question "can this API process be shut down right now" is answered by "does it have any requests in progress" by every web framework, host, and proxy in existence.

Comment: Very broad statement. Source (other than yourself)? Furthermore, you also state in another blog post that "As noted in the comments, the ASP.NET runtime will wait an arbitrary amount of time for your background tasks to complete."  (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html).

Comment: Can you provide a source stating ASP.NET guarantees request-extrinsic code will be run? The quote pulled from my blog is regarding work explicitly registered with ASP.NET, which doesn't apply here. And even if it's registered, it's a time-limited best-effort, not a guarantee. The op stated "I... want to make sure that it attempts to", so that's why I recommend the only solution with guaranteed work.

Comment: Of course not because I'm not making that claim. You are making the claim that code running outside of a request context is more likely to be killed via a process reset than code running inside. I mentioned in my answer that I've seen anecdotal reports of this - yours being the ultimate source of all of them - and would be interested in a source, preferably in the Microsoft docs or asp.net core source code, confirming this. Secondly, what effect would an open SignalR websocket connection (which I also mention) have on this alleged behavior? If you're right SignalR would basically not work.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with SignalR; I believe (but am not sure) that it depends on the underlying type of connection: I expect websockets would be terminated (and silently reconnected from the client side), but long-polling may wait for the poll to timeout before shutdown.

Comment: I can only speak to my experience, but as I said in my answer, I log every process start. I've never seen an unintended process restart aside from a catastrophe like out of memory or native code exception. To be fair, I also limit IIS to one process rather than let it do whatever it wants, so that could be part of it - but this would be an IIS question not ASP.NET. If you believe ASP.NET on its own initiative shuts down its own CPU process when it thinks its idle, despite active threads, I would really like to know that as I don't believe that to be the case.

Comment: I'm almost positive ASP.NET Core doesn't do that; I think ASP.NET on .NET Framework would do appdomain recycling, but I'm not sure if that was instead of the IIS process recycling or in addition to it.

Comment: Ok good maybe we're closer to the same page than I thought. Look I'm not saying your opinion isn't valid, but I think it should be clearer to readers that peoples' opinions on F&F are just those - opinions. There's no single right answer that fits every case. That's all. Don't mean to belabor this further. PS - Overall very good blog, critiques notwithstanding.

Answer (score -1):

There are more basic control flow issues with that logic what you trying to do. Your biggest problem is not the garantee about it is finished or not.

The example you present is very simple, but in real life example you will need some context in InternalSendEmail when it is executed. Because the request is completely served at the time it is executed, there will not be HttpContext, with all the consequences, for example you can not even log the IP address of the the request, not talking about all the more advanced context bound things like the user (or any other security principal) etc.

Of course you can pass anything as parameter (for example the IP address) but probably your logging infra (or your custom log enricher) will not work with that. Same is true for any other pipeline component which depends on the context.

Comment: "probably your logging infra (or your custom log enricher) will not work with that" - What makes you say that? You have no idea what his logging system needs or doesn't need. And anyway, experienced developers inject their own middleware to scaffold each request into a more appropriate abstraction layer and never let their business logic access the `HttpContext` directly.

Comment: ok, arguing on words. Please replace 'your' with 'a'. So the sentence is: "probably a logging infra...", so do not have to deal with am I a mind reader or not topic, You mentioned experienced developers, so "experienced developers" access HttpRequest via accessor object, but regardless the how and the place, the HttpContext will not exist at the time of exception handler, because the request already served, and HttpContext is gone. What I was trying to say, that having a Fire And Forget logic, and handling errors are not go together well. The OP trying to do that, which is an issue.

Comment: We're not just arguing over words. This is obviously a very divisive topic as evidenced by every answer and the question itself having several up and down votes. I'm not sure why but there is one camp that says this is fine if you are aware of the risks and another that seems to always feel the need to overstate those risks, sometimes melodramatically so. Doves and hawks I guess.

Comment: No it is not. To be short, Fire And Forget logic, and handling errors are not go together. The OP trying to do that (see the exception handler) which is an issue. The exception handler code is misleading, it will run out of context. This has nothing to do with the camps about is FF ok or not.

Comment: It's a problem that should be trivial to solve unless he's using some third party tool that absolutely requires the HttpContext, in which case he should be using something else as logging is likewise trivial. Your answer to me makes it sound like this is a dealbreaker.